# Decode base64 image and store on disk (using java) out of memory

Tags: java, tomcat, base64, out-of-memory

i need to store on disk a base64 image but i have an error: "Out of memory" when i decode base64 image into byte[]. The size image is about 6MB
This is my code:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(photo); //HERE I HAVE THE ERROR!!
log.debug("binary ok");
BufferedImage bfi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));    

String nomeEdata = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
String nomeImg = resourceBundle.getString("schede.pathSaveImage") + nomeEdata;

File outputfile = new File(nomeImg);
ImageIO.write(bfi , "png", outputfile);
bfi.flush();
```

Please, Any suggests?

Comment: Would it be possible to show us what data type photo is and how you obtained it?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the "photo" content to a temporary file and then read from it using a [Base64InputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html).

In the end, however, the `BufferedImage` will have the entire raw image in memory. This will require that you have a heap size large enough to accommodate this. You may just have to increase the Xmx value.

```
final BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new Base64InputStream(new ReaderInputStream(new StringReader(photo), "ascii"));

final File file = ...
final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
try
{
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new Base64OutputStream(fos));
}
finally 
{
    fos.close();
}
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please can you explain with an example? My goal is to write the base64 string into a file. In my case write in a "temporary file" is my goal.

Comment: What data type is `photo`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm tring your code but i should make a substring of photo object like this: String photoNew = photo.substring(photo.indexOf(",")+1); to remove the first part of base64 string. And now I have the same error: out of memory

Comment: Consider skipping the characters in the `StringReader` rather than calling `substring`. In the end, however, it seems like you really need to increase your Xmx value.   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#skip-long-